# What quantum entities are responsible for "classic" magnetism?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

What quantum entities give rise to what is known as "magnetism" in the Maxwell equations?

Comment: Do you mean the force Carriers? Because that would just be the photon

Comment: @user43087 what about the magnetic quantum number?

Comment: Have you looked at the Wikipedia entry on [Magnetism # Quantum mechanical origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetism#Quantum-mechanical_origin_of_magnetism)?

Comment: @KyleKanos now I have, thanks. But it's still unclear to me :/

Comment: That's fine for it to be unclear, but could you add what is unclear to you? That way, an answer can address what you're missing & you'll get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Magnetism can be considered to be a relativistic consequence of electrostatics. This is a questionable (but perhaps enlightening) derivation.

http://www.chip-architect.com/physics/Magnetism_from_ElectroStatics_and_SR.pdf